# How to adjust Bootstrap grid to display differently like my example in mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm wondering what the best way is to accomplish the below responsive design using Bootstrap 3.  I have only been able to get it to look somewhat like my goal, which is the following:

REGULAR-SIZED MONITOR GOAL:

[image: image one]

MOBILE DEVICE GOAL:

[image: image two]

What I have tried so far:  Here is the best I can do to accomplish the above.

HTML:

[image: code snipe 1]

CSS:

[image: code snipe 2]

300px is just going off of what looks decent on my screen, but I would prefer the responsive design to control the page shrinking and growing rather than this number.  What would work perfectly is to simply use text-align:left and text-align:right, but the problem with that is when the responsive design kicks in, the mobile device still has them on the left and right side instead of both of them on the left side.  I want them both on the left side stacked on top of each other.  My code works above, but I am pretty sure there is a better way.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first and foremost bootstrap has an `offset` kind of thing where instead of creating the space, or the `pads_to_right` you can just call a class in the grid system. offset sets the responsive margin with left element. Your code should look like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row"><!--rows help in the order of the div and positioning-->
        <div class="col-md-4">left text</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">right text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the grid system has `md` for medium, `lg` for Large, `xs` for extra-small and `sm` for small. All these are breakpoints for screen sizes so setting your code to column of `md-4` sets your div to a specific dimension on the medium size screen. So if you want to set something like that for mobile you have to also use `col-xs-dimension(1-12)`. The numbers that follow the screen size have to sum up to **12** . Read more about the grid system [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/).

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row"><!--rows help in the order of the div and positioning-->
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">left text</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-xs-12">right text</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So here i set the xs to 12 so it occupies the whole space and pushes the next div to the next line.

Comment: Just as a quick follow up question, is there a way I can get the "right text" part when it's on the larger screen (on the right side) even FURTHER to the right than your example results in?  Thanks again!

Comment: @user3089840 yhup you can modify the offset to 6 and col-md-2 in the second div so <div class="col-md-2 col-offset-6 col-xs-12">right text</div>